# How to Power 12V DC Motor For 30+ Hours

Tags: batteries, dc-motor, 12v

First time poster (and attempt at electrical engineering), thanks ahead of time for any guidance!

I am looking to power [this small DC 12v 10RPM motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0771F7XBH) - with the goal of having it run for around 30-40 hours. One of the potential solutions I am considering is to connect it to a 12V Deep Cycle Marine Battery (with a fuse & switch). I have three quick questions:

- Do we think this is a viable solution both in terms of powering the motor, and lasting for this period of time?
- Is there an easier solution out there, one that doesn't involve connecting it to a large [marine battery such as this](https://www.oreillyauto.com/detail/b/marine-4990/battery-accessories-16452/deep-cycle---marine-batteries-17354/220f7dcd7121/super-start-marine-group-size-24-top-post-battery/1stmate/4742397)? (Would any other battery source be viable?)

**Motor Specs:**

- No-load Speed: 10RPM at 12 Volts;
- Torque: 0.98N-m(8.68lb-in);
- Power: 1.8W;
- No-load Current: 0.15A;
- Load Current: 0.6A;
- Reduction Ratio: 1: 401;

**Deep Cycle Battery Specs**

- Battery Type: Starting;
- Cold Cranking Amps (CCA): 460 CCA;
- Marine Cranking Amps (MCA): 575 MCA;
- Cranking Amps (CA): 500 CA;
- Voltage (V): 12 Volt;

Thank you again for any guidance!

Comment: Current draw of said fan?

Comment: It's more about the load than the motor.... how much current does it draw when driving whatever it is driving?

Comment: No DCR specs , No load specs , no answer possible,.

Comment: do not put information into comments .... add the info to your question, then delete the comment .... physical size of the motor, the shaft and the gearbox is irrelevant to your question, so you can leave that out

Comment: What's the current draw of the motor?  This question is *unclear* without specs.  Once you have the current, this question is just about doing the math, not about motors.  What is the rating of the battery? *What* schematic? You should have been able to see for yourself that much necessary information is missing from the question.

Comment: Jsotola - Roger, updated the initial comment. Thanks! Olin - No need to be aggressive/angry, like I said, first time poster. I would appreciate any help, but, let's just try to stay kind here.

Comment: You've told us how the battery performs under extreme high current applications - which obviously doesn't matter here - but not its capacity, which does.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - Unfortunately the battery I'm looking at does not show capacity. May I ask what would be a target capacity I should look for out of a battery? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Less than an amp for up to 40 hours would suggest 40 amp-hours. Now, lead acid batteries don't like deep discharge, so I'd suggest doubling it, 80Ah "leisure" or RV batteries would be suitable.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - Thanks so much, this is incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

While you say that your specified battery does not show capacity, it almost certainly does - sort of. For automotive/marine lead-acid batteries the number of interest is the reserve capacity. This is the duration it can provide 25 amps for. Multiply reserve capacity (in hours) times 25 and you get (sort of) capacity in A-hr.

I say sort of, since in general batteries will have better capacity at lower currents. But let's stick with it. Your alternative battery has a reserve capacity of 70 minutes (1.16 hours) for a nominal (high-current) capacity of about 29 A-hr. Your motor is rated for a full-load current of 0.6 A, times 40 hours means you need a 24 A-hr battery. Your alternative will almost certainly do, especially considering that your 0.6 A is less than 25 by a factor of 40, so the battery will almost certainly do better than a simple analysis indicates.

But, of course, you haven't told us what you actually expect the motor to draw, so the results may be even better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out, or measure, how much current the motor will draw when it is turning whatever it is driving. How much current it draws will depend on the mechanical load in the system, and, as such, how much charge the battery needs to supply over the number of hours you need to run it.

If it draws the full 0.6A when loaded, and run it continuously, then you will need a battery with at least an 24Ahr battery to run it for 40 hours.

If you stop and start the motor frequently, that number can rise markedly.

---

As for your 2nd and 3rd questions... WHAT SCHEMATIC?.. easier than what?... you seem to be missing a lot of information in the question...

Comment: Thanks for this information, it is appreciated. In regards to the 2nd and 3rd question, my schematic is incredibly simple - as this is my first stab at electrical engineering, and is more of a general plan/brainstorm solution. I appreciate your guidance/support though - especially with the limited amount of information provided. This is all kind of new to me, so I'm grateful for the help of community members such as yourself. Adding the battery specs to the initial question.